# Concat strings in a shell script

Tags: bash, string-concatenation

How can I concat strings in shell?  Is it just...

```
var = 'my';
var .= 'string';
```

?

Comment: FYI variables in bash can't have spaces around the `=`. It has to be next to the name and the value.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

How about this:

```
var="${var}string"
```

Answer (score 30):

It depends on the shell, but since question was tagged bash:

```
var='my'
var=$var'string'
```

Answer (score 11):

No. For various reasons.

```
# most sh-compatible shells
var="my"
var="$var string"

# advanced shells
var="my"
var+=" string"
```