# Concatenating string read from file with string literals creates jumbled output

Tags: string, macos, bash, concatenation

My problem is that the result is jumbled. Consider this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT="filelist.txt"

i=0;
while read label
do
    i=$[$i+1]
    echo "HELLO${label}WORLD"
done <<< $'1\n2\n3\n4'

i=0;
while read label
do
    i=$[$i+1]
    echo "HELLO${label}WORLD"
done < "$INPUT"
```

filelist.txt

```
5
8
15
67
...
```

The first loop, with the immediate input (through something I believe is called a *herestring* (the `<<<` operator) gives the expected output

```
HELLO1WORLD
HELLO2WORLD
HELLO3WORLD
HELLO4WORLD
```

The second loop, which reads from the file, gives the following jumbled output:

```
WORLD5
WORLD8
WORLD15
WORLD67
```

I've tried `echo $label`: This works as expected ***in both cases***, but the concatenation fails in the second case as described. Further, the **exact same code** works on my Win 7, git-bash environment. This issue is on OSX 10.7 Lion.

[How to concatenate strings in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10263/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-bash) |
[Bash variables concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325722/bash-variables-concatenation) |
[concat string in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445259/concat-string-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 2):

Well, just as I was about to hit post, the solution hit me. Sharing here so someone else can find it - it took me 3 hours to debug this (despite being on SO for almost all that time) so I see value in addressing this specific (common) use case.

The problem is that `filelist.txt` was created in Windows. This means it has CRLF line endings, while OSX (like other Unix-like environments) expects LF only line endings. (See more here: [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types))

I used the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373888/converting-newline-formatting-from-mac-to-windows) to convert the file before consumption. Using `sed` I managed to replace only the final line's carriage return, so I stuck to known guns and went for the `perl` approach. Final script is below:

```
 #!/bin/bash
INPUTFILE="filelist.txt"
INPUT=$(perl -pe 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g' "$INPUTFILE")

i=0;
while read label
do
    i=$[$i+1]
    echo "HELLO${label}WORLD"
done <<< $'INPUT'
```

Question has been asked in a different form at [Bash: Concatenating strings fails when read from certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482023/bash-concatenating-strings-fails-when-read-from-certain-files)